# how to override qscrollbar onclick default behaviour

Tags: qt, pyqt

When you click on QScrollBar's "page control area" ('c' on the image), it will scroll one page. What I want is to make it scroll to the full, just like when you choose "Scroll here" context menu item.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works for me, python 3.4 pyqt 5.4.

pixelPosToRangeValue is taken from qt source

```
def wrapEF(ef):
    w = QObject()
    w.eventFilter = ef
    return w

def sbEventFilter(s, e):
    q = s
    if (e.type() == QEvent.MouseButtonPress and e.button() == Qt.LeftButton
        or e.type() == QEvent.MouseButtonDblClick):
        #pixelPosToRangeValue(pos)
        opt = QStyleOptionSlider()
        q.initStyleOption(opt)
        gr = q.style().subControlRect(QStyle.CC_ScrollBar, opt, 
                                               QStyle.SC_ScrollBarGroove, q)
        sr = q.style().subControlRect(QStyle.CC_ScrollBar, opt, 
                                               QStyle.SC_ScrollBarSlider, q)
        if q.orientation() == Qt.Horizontal:
            sliderLength = sr.width()
            sliderMin = gr.x()
            sliderMax = gr.right() - sliderLength + 1
            if q.layoutDirection() == Qt.RightToLeft:
                opt.upsideDown = not opt.upsideDown
            dt = sr.width()/2
            pos = e.pos().x()
        else:
            sliderLength = sr.height()
            sliderMin = gr.y()
            sliderMax = gr.bottom() - sliderLength + 1
            dt = sr.height()/2
            pos = e.pos().y()
        r = QStyle.sliderValueFromPosition(q.minimum(), q.maximum(),
                                           pos - sliderMin - dt, 
                                           sliderMax - sliderMin, opt.upsideDown)
        #pixelPosToRangeValue, 
        q.setValue(r)
    return q.eventFilter(s, e)


self.scrollBarEF = wrapEF(sbEventFilter)
self.hscrollbar.installEventFilter(self.scrollBarEF)
self.vscrollbar.installEventFilter(self.scrollBarEF)
```

Answer (score 3):

That's quite an interesting question. To find out an answer, we need to take a look at [QScrollBar source](http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/widgets/widgets/qscrollbar.cpp) and find out two things:

- How to determine which part of the scroll bar has been clicked;
- How to trigger "Scroll Here" behavior.

The answer to the first question lies in `QScrollBar::mousePressEvent` implementation. It turns out that `QStyle::hitTestComplexControl` does just what we need. What for the second question, just search "Scroll here" and you'll see that `QScrollBarPrivate::pixelPosToRangeValue` is used to convert event position to slider value. Unfortunately, we don't have access to functions of this private class, so we're forced to reimplement it. Now let's apply gained knowledge and implement new behavior in a subclass:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui


class ModifiedScrollBar(QtGui.QScrollBar):

  def __init__(self, parent = None):
    super(ModifiedScrollBar, self).__init__(parent)

  def mousePressEvent(self, event):
    if event.button() == QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
      opt = QtGui.QStyleOptionSlider()
      self.initStyleOption(opt)
      control = self.style().hitTestComplexControl(QtGui.QStyle.CC_ScrollBar, opt, 
                                                   event.pos(), self)
      if (control == QtGui.QStyle.SC_ScrollBarAddPage or 
          control == QtGui.QStyle.SC_ScrollBarSubPage):
        # scroll here
        gr = self.style().subControlRect(QtGui.QStyle.CC_ScrollBar, opt, 
            QtGui.QStyle.SC_ScrollBarGroove, self)
        sr = self.style().subControlRect(QtGui.QStyle.CC_ScrollBar, opt, 
            QtGui.QStyle.SC_ScrollBarSlider, self)
        if self.orientation() == QtCore.Qt.Horizontal:
          pos = event.pos().x()
          sliderLength = sr.width()
          sliderMin = gr.x()
          sliderMax = gr.right() - sliderLength + 1
          if (self.layoutDirection() == QtCore.Qt.RightToLeft):
              opt.upsideDown = not opt.upsideDown
        else:
          pos = event.pos().y()
          sliderLength = sr.height()
          sliderMin = gr.y()
          sliderMax = gr.bottom() - sliderLength + 1
        self.setValue(QtGui.QStyle.sliderValueFromPosition(
            self.minimum(), self.maximum(), pos - sliderMin, 
            sliderMax - sliderMin, opt.upsideDown))
        return

    return super(ModifiedScrollBar, self).mousePressEvent(event)


def main():
  app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
  edit = QtGui.QTextEdit()
  #uncomment for testing horizontal scrollbar
  #edit.setLineWrapMode(QtGui.QTextEdit.NoWrap)
  edit.setPlainText("Lorem ipsum...")
  edit.setVerticalScrollBar(ModifiedScrollBar())
  edit.setHorizontalScrollBar(ModifiedScrollBar())
  edit.show()

  sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

Comment: I am going to test it

Comment: You cannot drag after you pressed. Need to remove half of slider width. Modify answer so it is possible to click and drag slider and I ll accept it